# Postgres client tools like tablePlus, pgadmin DBvisualizer are not working with .pgpass with RDS token

Tags: postgresql

When i'm using normal password with .pgpassfile syntax it's working just fine but when i replace the normal password with RDS token it is failing with error message.
I tried the steps/instructions mentioned in [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-pgpass.html) but that didn't help. I'm suspecting there is some issue with libpq/pgpassfile logic which restrict the client from accessing the correct password.

Error message:

```
An error occurred while establishing the connection:

Long Message:
FATAL: PAM authentication failed for user "readonly_user"

Details:
   Type: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
   SQL State: 28000
```

Comment: What exact version of libpq are you using?

Comment: libpq.dylib -> libpq.5.6.dylib
libpq.5.dylib -> libpq.5.6.dylib
libpq.5.6.dylib

Comment: I am using DBvisualizer client for connecting the DB. I'm not sure which version of libpq they are using.

Comment: 5.6 was released with PostgreSQL 9.3, so it is pretty old.  There used to be a limit on pgpass line length (enforced by silent truncation), which was removed more recently than that, I believe.